# Finding key word

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
res = dict(filter(lambda item: search_key in item[0], dict1.items()))
list_keys = [ k for k in res ]
```

Here is my code. I want it to only include the list of words, not any additional concatenation with the exception of `-`,"cats" like I am searching `cat` I want the list not to return `catspoon`.

Comment: Which resource is your start. dict1 or res? So what contains the words?

Comment: dict1 contains the items

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to match whole words.

```
import re

search_key = r'\bcat\b'
res = dict(filter(lambda item: re.search(search_key, item[0]), dict1.items()))
list_keys = [ k for k in res ]
```

Comment: this causes the ones with "-"  to only print out. if I have "this is a cat" it does not print the phrase out, or if I have "this brand 'w' cat" nothing prints but the ones with "-"

Comment: The question said that words could be separated by `-`, it didn't say anything about spaces. I've updated the answer to show how to do it using a regular expression.

Comment: The current problem is I am still getting "cats" printed out not just "cat".

Comment: This shouldn't match that.

Comment: Are you sure you have `\b` at the beginning and end of the regexp?